# Limiting what affiliate's Google Tag Manager can inject into my site

Tags: security, google-tag-manager, tracking, affiliate, tracking-pixel

I am managing a website where we sell products. We have an affiliate program.

I want to facilitate the affiliates the tracking for them to optimize the campaigns.

Currently we display a different Facebook pixel for each affiliate.

Say affiliate `33` has FB pixel `FB-000333` and affiliate `44` has FB pixel `FB-999999` then if one comes with `?affiliate-id=33` then I currenly inject the facebook pixel `FB-000333` but if the query was `?affiliate-id=44` then I inject FB pixel `FB-999999`.

That's all under control.

But they want to try other pixels, like twitter, google, tik-tok, etc.

We were planning to set the Google Tag Manager (GTM) instead of a specific pixel, so they can freely control what pixels to put where.

Say the previous affiliate `33` has GTM id `G-aaa` and affiliate `44` has GTM id `G-bbb`.

### Benefit

Then if coming via `?affiliate-id=33` I will only inject `G-aaa` which in turn allows the affiliate `33` to inject the FB pixel `FB-000333` by himself in his GTM's admin panel. And if he ever wants to load a twitter pixel -say- `TW-xxxyyy` then he can do it at his will. He has not to wait us for any change.

### Counterpart

Nevertheless, installing GTM allows them to inject nearly "anything" in the page and could completely mess the page if they inject something that is not properly controlled.

## Question

May I put a GTM for the affiliate in my page but tell the GTM API to allow only "certain types of injections"? For example tell GTM "You can only inject the FB pixel, the Twitter pixel and the Google pixel" and if they want to put TikTok it will not be loaded until we review it is "safe for us"?